# Can Paypal IPN payment_status change from Completed into another status for a transaction?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

If I have received an IPN that tells me the transaction (txn_id=123) is completed (i.e. payment_status=Completed).

Is this possible that for some reasons I will later receive another IPN that tells me the payment_status of the same transaction (txn_id=123) has changed from "Completed" to another status.

Anyone has experience with this?

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some threads on the PayPal Developer Network, payments that have been completed *can* be reversed in certain cases. This would result in another IPN, stating that the payment has been reversed. See:

- [Is payment_status 'Completed' really final?](https://www.x.com/thread/30903)
- [IPN + Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/thread/41424)

From the second thread:

> **Q:** [...] if my payment already completed. it won't be reverse / chargeback suddenly without my authorization. right?
>
> **A:** [...] it is possible that a completed payment can be reversed without your authorization. [...]

So, although it probably won't happen very often, payments that have been reported 'Complete' can still change status afterwards.

Comment: To add: that would usually happen within minutes of a transaction being completed.

Answer (score 0):

I think no. If you received this notification and status is "Completed", it means that money have been already transfered.
But you should check that you received this request from PayPal. Because everybody can request you IPN url with corrupted data.

Comment: If Paypal has a state chart that clearly shows what event makes a transaction turn into another payment_status, that will be great.